# Why isn't my python solution for a Project Euler problem working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, primes

I've been trying project euler problems and I can't seem to solve problem 7 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=7). A large problem is that my solution didn't work so I tried rewriting it but it still refuses to give me an output which tells me I went wrong somewhere.

```
##Problem 7 UNSOLVED
a= 10
b= 1
for c in range (1,a//2):
    while b < 10002:
        if  a % c == 0:
         a=a+1
        else:
         b = b+1
         a= a+ 1
         print (a)

print (a,b)

##Problem 7 v2
n = 10
p = 4
while p <100002:
     for i in range (2,n//2):
        if n % i == 0:
            break
        else:
            p = p +1
        n = n +1

print(n, p)
```

Comment: You're counting a number as a prime if there's any number that doesn't divide it. It's only a prime if you get to the end of the loop and never found a divisor.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about testing if a number is prime, I suggest you click on the tag to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Your primalty test was not implemented correctly. At the moment, you're adding up your variable *p* each time your number *n* has no divisor. If you have 13 for an example as your *n*, your *p* will be increased by 5 or 6, instead of 1.

You need to rewrite your primalty check, so that it adds 1 to *p* if *n* is prime, and add nothing to *p* if *n* is not prime.

You could write a function for that, which makes your code more readable and easier to use.

Such a primalty check function could look like this:

```
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(3, int(n**.5)+1):

        if n % i == 0:
            return 0
    return 1
```

```
>>> is_prime(10)
0
>>> is_prime(11)
1
```

This function is not optimized for speed, but it works in my solution for Euler problem #7 to get the correct output in 0.132s.

Beware, that this test is working for odd numbers higher than 11 only, because lower numbers will not have any iteration, 'cause their root is less than three.

Comment: Hi I'm really sorry but in the primalty check function shouldn't the "Return 1" be under some kind of "else". Also when I just tried it with seemingly random numbers it shows numbers such as 10 as prime? Not sure why?

Comment: My bad.. This is working for all odd numbers higher than 11, which is the reason I started counting at 13 with the prime counter *p* set to 6. So you need to skip the first 6 prime numbers to make this work. But this test is a little faster than yours, because its iterating in two steps and stopping at the root of your number, which can make a big difference when handling big numbers.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Anyways, I used your primality check and after a few issues on my part I seemed  to have gotten the right answer :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the Prime Number theorem to estimate the size of the 10_0001st prime number.
2. Set up a Sieve of Eratosthenes large enough to include that number.
3. Count through the sieve to find the 10_001st prime.

Your code for the sieve will be useful for other Project Euler problems.

Comment: Thank you! I just started with python but I will make sure to look that up and see how it works.